# AS3 SQLite - Select statement to get names from a column but only once, if they appear many times

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sqlite, air, adobe

I was wondering if anyone knows how to write a SELECT statement for SQLite to get all names from, lets say a teacher column, but only once. So lets say in the teacher column...Mr. Smith shows up several times, mrs. Jones shows up several times, how can I get a list of all the teachers names, but only once?  Not lots of objects of the same name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `DISTINCT` keyword to remove duplicates from the result

```
SELECT DISTINCT teacher_name FROM teacher
```